# Function jQuery retornar mensagem validação, em vez de alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

Eu tenho esta função, que funciona perfeitamente:

```
  $('#FornecedorNovo').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "/Fornecedor/VerificaInscricao";
    var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
    var form = this,
        $form = $(form); // Salvamos o formulário atual em uma variável

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { insc: Insc },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == true) {
                alert('Já existe esta inscrição estadual cadastrada para outro fornecedor.');
                $("#InscricaoEstadual").focus();
            } else {
                var url1 = "/Fornecedor/VerificaDocumento";
                var Documento = $("#Documento").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    data: { documento: Documento },
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.resultado == true) {
                            alert('Já existe este CNPJ/CPF cadastrado para outro fornecedor.');
                            $("#Documento").focus();
                        }
                        else {
                            $form.off('submit').submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Porém ela aparece um alert, eu queria que a mensagem aparecesse igual a validação de campos, no `<span asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual" class="text-danger"></span>` por exemplo.
É possível?

Comment: Provavelmente você deveria adicionar a tag do framework que você está usando. Pode ter uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso que não seja apenas javascript ou jquery.

Comment: @fernandosavio adicionei. trabalho com asp.net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não entendo de Asp.Net, uma solução com jQuery seria pegar o elemento que você quer inserir a mensagem de erro com jQuery e alterar seu HTML. No seu caso seria trocar a linha:

```
alert('Já existe este CNPJ/CPF cadastrado para outro fornecedor.');
```

por:

```
$('[asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual"]').html('Já existe este CNPJ/CPF cadastrado para outro fornecedor.');
```

Para melhorar a performance você poderia salvar o resultado de `$('[asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual"]')` em uma variável para não ter que procurar a cada requisição ajax, ou melhor, definir um `id` para o elemento e usar um [seletor de ids](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) ao invés de usar o [seletor de atributos](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) utilizado no exemplo.

Comment: Tentei desta forma, porém não aparece a mensagem, e não retorna erro no console.

Comment: Ele não estava aceitando o `'[asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual"]` então defini um `id` para ele, e passei na `function` `$("#messageI").html(data.mensagem);`e deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Vou adicionar a documentação do seletor de atributos para deixar a pergunta melhor documentada. Mas a maneira que você resolveu, usando id, é a mais performática mesmo.